# Setting the pageSize of Extjs bufferedstore based on a config file

Tags: extjs, extjs4, store, extjs4.1, extjs-stores

I have an Extjs bufferedstore as below:

```
Ext.define('myStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.BufferedStore',

requires: [
    'myStoremodel' // model that the store takes in 
],

storeId: 'myTeststore',

model: 'myStoremodel',

remoteSort: true,
buffered: true,
leadingBufferZone: 2,
trailingBufferZone: 2,
pageSize: 10,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: "/fetch/getNameList" // the API which returns data to load,
    timeout: 5 * 60 * 1000,
    reader: {
        rootProperty: 'data.name',
        totalProperty: 'data.recordSize'
    },
    simpleSortMode: true
}
});
```

I am looking to make the pageSize variable (change the size according to change made in config file). How can I read the value from an external config file? How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give you one **pretty basic** but possibile solution, you could create an API to get your frontend defaults config (like the pageSize of ExtJs stores).

Then at the opening of your webapp, as the very first step, you could make a single call to that api and save the result where you prefer (window object, cookies,...).

Image having an object in response like below and saving it in a window static variable:

```
window.myFrontEndConfigs = {
    pageSize: 20
};
```

So in your store definition you could use something like this:

```
Ext.define('myStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.BufferedStore',
    ...
    pageSize: window.myFrontEndConfigs.pageSize
    ...
}
```

I repeat this is a pretty "Stone-Age" solution, but knowing little to zero info on your front/back end leave me with low options...

*-Edit-*

Nothing stops you to just have a new js file dedicated to contain exclusively a function that return your configs. Just add it on your page and boom, done, config loaded and available. It is just that I like having the config on my backend cause I never know in the future if it needs to be dynamic it self based on user, group,...

**myConfigs.js**

```
function myFrontEndConfigs() {
    return {
        pageSize: 20
    };
}
```

And then in your store:

```
Ext.define('myStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.BufferedStore',
    ...
    pageSize: myFrontEndConfigs().pageSize
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I actually have the pageLimit variable as part of the same API response that gets returned as part of url: "/fetch/getNameList" which is the proxy URL of the buffered store. Is there any way to set the pageSize from the response I get from proxy without making any additional API call?

Comment: The pageSize config is something you need to set **BEFORE** making the actual api call with one of the .load methods of the store.

So no, you cant read the pageSize config and load the store by just making one call.

For the pagination to work, your API "/fetch/getNameList" should return a **total** property, meanwhile the pageSize params (page, start, limit) will be automatically generated by the store load and given to the API as inputs.